The "Euler Product formula" for general multiplicative functions
For the totient function $\phi$, we have the well known "Euler's product formula" (as named on Wikipedia)  $$\phi(n) = n \prod_{p | n} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right)$$
This is easy to show knowing multiplicativity of $\phi(n)$ and the fact that $\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1}(p-1)$. However, I was applying the Sieve method to find an upper bound for the number of integers $k$ such that some separable polynomial $f(k)$ avoided some residue classes, and a quantity of the form
$ \phi(n) \prod_{p | n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\phi(p)} \right) $
showed up. I realized that the Euler product formula is just the statement that if for multiplicative functions $g(n)$ we define $$F_g(n) := g(n) \prod_{p | n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{g(p)} \right)$$ then for $g(n) = n$, we have $F_g(n) = \phi(n)$. Further, $F_g(n)$ is always multiplicative as when $(m,n) = 1$ we have
$$ F_g(mn) = g(mn) \prod_{p | mn} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{g(p)} \right) = g(m) \prod_{p |m} \left( 1- \frac{1}{g(p)} \right) g(n) \prod_{p |n} \left( 1 -\frac{1}{g(p)} \right) = F_g(m)F_g(n) $$
So my question is: What multiplicative function is $F_g(n)$ when $g(n) = \phi(n)$? Is there an expression for it in terms of the well-known arithmetic functions? If not $g(n) = \phi(n)$, besides $g(n) = n$ for what other multiplicative $g(n)$ can we find $F_g(n)$ in terms of standard arithmetic functions? Another quantity that shows up while sieving for a slightly different set is, for $ a \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$
$$ F^a_g(n) := g(n) \prod_{p | n} \left( 1 - \frac{a}{g(p)} \right) $$
In particular, $F^2_{\phi(n)}$ had shown up, but I realized I could not even find an expression for $F^a_{\text{Id}(n)}$ where $\text{Id}(n) := n$ for $a > 1$.
If it helps, even resolving the question for $n$ squarefree is of interest, but for the purposes I intend to work with it for I only need to estimate the growth of this quantity with $n$

A lot can be deduced from the following property:
\begin{equation}
\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{1}{x-k}\right)=1-\frac{k+1}{x}
\end{equation}
Now, we define
\begin{align*}
F^a_g(n) &:= g(n) \prod_{p | n} \left( 1 - \frac{a}{g(p)} \right) \\
F_g(n) &:= g(n) \prod_{p | n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{g(p)} \right)=F^1_g(n)\\
\end{align*}
Now, when $g=\text{Id}$, in other words $g(n)=n$, the Euler's product formula tells us that
$$F^1_\text{Id}(n)=\phi(n)=n \prod_{p | n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)$$
So, when evaluating $F_{\phi}$, we have:
\begin{align*}
 F_{\phi}(n) &= \phi(n) \prod_{p | n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\phi(p)}\right) \\
 &= n \prod_{p | n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)\prod_{p | n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p-1}\right) \\
 &= n \prod_{p | n} \left(1 - \frac{2}{p}\right) \\
 &= F_{\text{Id}}^2(n) \\
\end{align*}
This leads to a recursion:
\begin{align*}
 F_{\text{Id}}^k(n) &=n \prod_{p | n} \left(1 - \frac{k}{p}\right) \\
 &= n \prod_{p | n}\left(1 - \frac{k-1}{p}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{p-k+1}\right) \\
 &= F_{\text{Id}}^{k-1}(n)\prod_{p | n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p-(k-1)}\right) \\
 &= F_{\text{Id}}^{k-1}(n)\prod_{p | n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{F_{\text{Id}}^{k-1}(p)}\right) \\
 &= F_{F_{\text{Id}}^{k-1}}(n)
\end{align*}
But we can apply this recursion with every starting function, for example you asked for $F_{\phi}^2(n)$:
\begin{align*}
 F_{\phi}^2(n) &=\phi(n)\prod_{p | n}\left(1 - \frac{2}{\phi(p)}\right) \\
 &=\phi(n)\prod_{p | n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{\phi(p)}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{\phi(p)-1}\right) \\
 &=F_{\phi}(n)\prod_{p | n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{\phi(p)-1}\right) \\
 &=F_{\phi}(n)\prod_{p | n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p-2}\right) \\
 &=F_{\phi}(n)\prod_{p | n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{F_{\phi}(p)}\right) \\
 &=F_{F_{\phi}}(n) \\
\end{align*}
I recognise that all of this is not computationally helpful, but I think it partially answers the question, providing links between the functions defined in the OP.
To answer your second question "for what other multiplicative $g(n)$
can we find $F_g(n)$
in terms of standard arithmetic functions", if $g(n)=\mu(n)$, the Möbius function, then
\begin{align*}
  F_{\mu}^a(n) &= \mu(n)\prod_{p | n}\left(1 - \frac{a}{\mu(p)}\right) \\
 &= \mu(n)\prod_{p | n}(1+a) \\
 &= \mu(n)\cdot (1+a)^{\omega(n)} 
\end{align*}
where $\omega(n)$ is the prime omega function.
Similarly, when $g(n)=\sigma_0(n)$ is the number of divisor function, we have
$$F_{\sigma_0}^a(n)=\sigma_0(n)\prod_{p | n}\left(1-\frac{a}{2}\right)=\sigma_0(n)\left(1-\frac{a}{2}\right)^{\omega(n)} $$
